# Why do I need to reserve more than 4 bytes for a JNA pointer to receive a long when sizeof(long) is 4?

Tags: java, jna

I'm using JNA to communicate with a native C library compiled with Visual Studio 2015. I'm working on a 64-bit machine. I'm trying to receive the value of a C-function through a long pointer `long *pdays` argument. I'm getting the following exception:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Bounds exceeds available space :
>   size=4, offset=8  at com.sun.jna.Memory.boundsCheck(Memory.java:220)
>     at com.sun.jna.Memory.getLong(Memory.java:498)

I don't understand what I'm missing here, if I reserve just 4 bytes of memory for the pointer this results in the crash above, however if I reserve 8 everything goes fine. However sizeof(long) returns 4, so why do I need to reserve more than 4 bytes?

```
    System.out.println(NativeLong.SIZE); // --> 4
    System.out.println(Native.LONG_SIZE); // --> 4

    // Pointer pDays = new Memory(Native.LONG_SIZE); Results in IndexOutOfBoundsException
    Pointer pDays = new Memory(8); // 

    nativeLib.GetDaysUntilExpiration(pDays);
    return pDays.getLong(0); // crashes here when reserving just 4 bytes
```

Comment: In java, a long is always 8 bytes. Perhaps you want getInt to read 4 bytes

Comment: It's just an idea without warranty, it's a long time ago and my C skills are a little bit rusty, but on a x64 bit machine/OS (I don't know if you use one) a C pointer should be 8 Bytes large... Maybe this is the reason for this issue

Comment: I would not use Pointer and Memory directly but i would use a NativeLongByReference: https://java-native-access.github.io/jna/4.2.0/com/sun/jna/ptr/NativeLongByReference.html

Comment: The C function argument is a pointer, using a NativeLongByReference would result in a "LongByReference cannot be converted to Pointer", i.e. incompatible type error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It crashes because you are trying to read 8 bytes from native memory which has allocated only 4 bytes.

It doesn't matter what the native type is, or that it's only 4 bytes.  The `Memory` is simply holding 4 bytes that you could interpret in any fashion you wished.  You could get a `byte[]` array, or an `int` (with those 4 bytes) or even a `short` or `byte` reading only that number of bytes.  You could even try a `String` (although without a null terminator, you'd probably read much more than the 4 bytes allowed, and who knows what you would get, so that would be dangerous.)

You have asked to get a Java `long` which is an 8-byte variable; accordingly, the code checks to see whether the next 8 bytes from your offset fit inside the allocated memory.  The code from `Memory.java` has this hardcoded:

```
boundsCheck(offset, 8);
```

The javadoc is clear about why this is:

> Indirect the native pointer to `malloc` space, a la `Pointer.getLong`.
>   But this method performs a bounds checks to ensure that the
>   indirection does not cause memory outside the `malloc`ed space to be
>   accessed.

The correct way to do what you're doing, where you don't manually allocate the space, is to simply use a `NativeLongByReference`.   JNA will take care of the allocation of space and retrieval of the value on its own, and you won't have to worry about the native size.

```
NativeLongByReference pDays = new NativeLongByReference();
nativeLib.GetDaysUntilExpiration(pDays);
return pDays.getValue().longValue();
```

EDIT: I note in your comment you say "The C function argument is a pointer, using a NativeLongByReference would result in a "LongByReference cannot be converted to Pointer" -- this is not an issue with the C function, but with the JNA mapping in your interface.  Better to change the JNA mapping of `GetDaysUntilExpiration` to take a `NativeLongByReference` argument.  If you can't change the JNA mapping of that function, you could work around it by using `pDays.getPointer()` as the argument.